# Safari: Not able to get the SVG element html through jquery

Tags: jquery, safari

I am trying to get the html of SVG elements through javascript. I am able to get the html in all browser except safari. I checked the console then it is showing this error

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object
```

I have prepared a fiddle also here is link: http://bit.ly/1o1CAs2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

SVG's are xml documents

```
var svg = document.getElementById('svg_root'); // or whatever you call it
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var str = serializer.serializeToString(svg);
```

.html() uses javascript function innerHTML which is for html, not svg.

Comment: Ok.It gives the require output, but then why it works for all other browsers.

Comment: probably it depends on your safari version and how it render svg elements

Answer (score 0):

```
var svg = document.getElementById('svg_root');
alert(svg.parentElement.innerHTML);
```

worked for me